# Is the current Ruby method called via super?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, subclass, super, ruby-2.3

Within a method at runtime, is there a way to know if that method has been called via `super` in a subclass? E.g.

```
module SuperDetector
  def via_super?
    # what goes here?
  end
end

class Foo
  include SuperDetector

  def bar
    via_super? ? 'super!' : 'nothing special'
  end
end

class Fu < Foo
  def bar
    super
  end
end

Foo.new.bar # => "nothing special"
Fu.new.bar  # => "super!"
```

How could I write `via_super?`, or, if necessary, `via_super?(:bar)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate mix between [my other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34736997/2423164), [@mudasobwa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34737122/2423164) and [@sawa's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34737405/2423164) answers plus recursion support:

```
module SuperDetector
  def self.included(clazz)
    unless clazz.instance_methods.include?(:via_super?)
      clazz.send(:define_method, :via_super?) do
        first_caller_location = caller_locations.first
        calling_method = first_caller_location.base_label

        same_origin = ->(other_location) do
          first_caller_location.lineno == other_location.lineno and
            first_caller_location.absolute_path == other_location.absolute_path
        end

        location_changed = false
        same_name_stack = caller_locations.take_while do |location|
          should_take = location.base_label == calling_method and !location_changed
          location_changed = !same_origin.call(location)
          should_take
        end

        self.kind_of?(clazz) and !same_origin.call(same_name_stack.last)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The only case that wont work (AFAIK) is if you have indirect recursion  in the base class, but I don't have ideas how to handle it with anything short of parsing the code.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably a better way, but the general idea is that `Object#instance_of?` is restricted only to the current class, rather than the hierarchy:

```
module SuperDetector
  def self.included(clazz)
    clazz.send(:define_method, :via_super?) do
      !self.instance_of?(clazz)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include SuperDetector

  def bar
    via_super? ? 'super!' : 'nothing special'
  end
end

class Fu < Foo
  def bar
    super
  end
end

Foo.new.bar # => "nothing special"
Fu.new.bar  # => "super!"
```

---

However, note that this doesn't require explicit `super` in the child. If the child has no such method and the parent's one is used, `via_super?` will still return `true`. I don't think there is a way to catch only the `super` case other than inspecting the stack trace or the code itself.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if both, parent and child include `SuperDetector`.

Comment: @Stefan `unless instance_methods.include?`

Comment: @mudasobwa that would prevent the child from using `SuperDetector`

Comment: @Stefan sounds like I figured it out: check for ancestors + define method if and only it was not defined on ancestors does likely do a trick.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simpler (almost trivial) approach, but you have to pass both, current class and method name: (I've also changed the method name from `via_super?` to `called_via?`)

```
module CallDetector
  def called_via?(klass, sym)
    klass == method(sym).owner
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
class A
  include CallDetector

  def foo
    called_via?(A, :foo) ? 'nothing special' : 'super!'
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    super
  end
end

class C < A
end

A.new.foo # => "nothing special"
B.new.foo # => "super!"
C.new.foo # => "nothing special"
```

Answer (score 3):

An addendum to an excellent @ndn approach:

```
module SuperDetector
  def self.included(clazz)
    clazz.send(:define_method, :via_super?) do
      self.ancestors[1..-1].include?(clazz) &&
        caller.take(2).map { |m| m[/(?<=`).*?(?=')/] }.reduce(&:==)
        # or, as by @ndn: caller_locations.take(2).map(&:label).reduce(&:==)
    end unless clazz.instance_methods.include? :via_super?
  end
end

class Foo
  include SuperDetector

  def bar
    via_super? ? 'super!' : 'nothing special'
  end
end

class Fu < Foo
  def bar
    super
  end
end

puts Foo.new.bar # => "nothing special"
puts Fu.new.bar # => "super!"
```

Here we use [`Kernel#caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) to make sure that the name of the method called matches the name in super class. This approach likely requires some additional tuning in case of not direct descendant (`caller(2)` should be changed to more sophisticated analysis,) but you probably get the point.

**UPD** thanks to @Stefan’s comment to the other answer, updated with `unless defined` to make it to work when both `Foo` and `Fu` `include SuperDetector`.

**UPD2** using ancestors to check for super instead of straight comparison.

Comment: Pretty much - yes. Just use `Kernel#caller_locations` and call `location` on them, rather than parsing with regex.

Comment: @ndn you meant call `label`, right? I do not see any advantage of it, but updated :)

Comment: The `unless` fails if you subclass `Fu` and expect `SuperDetector` for `Fu` to behave properly (aka will always return `false` even for methods defined in `Fu`).

Comment: @ndn there should be comparison against ancestors, I believe, not `self` against `included`.

Comment: Wouldn't `self.ancestors.include?(clazz)` always be true?

Comment: Still don't see the point. It's equivalent to `self.class != clazz`.

Comment: In other words if `Foo < Bar < Baz`, `Baz` and `Bar` include the module, `Baz` has a method `baz`, but `Bar` doesn't, then calling `super` from `Foo#baz` will still return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Improved, following Stefan's suggestion.

```
module SuperDetector
  def via_super?
    m0, m1 = caller_locations[0].base_label, caller_locations[1]&.base_label
    m0 == m1 and
    (method(m0).owner rescue nil) == (method(m1).owner rescue nil)
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't the two `method(mX).owner` calls evaluate in the current context and always be equal? (assuming `m0 == m1`)

Comment: Both `m0` and `m1` are strings and since they are equal, `call_whatever_func_on_it(m0)` would be identically equal to `call_whatever_func_on_it(m1)`. Am I missing smth?

Comment: I was afraid what happens when there is a recursive call. But I haven't thought much. Maybe I can simplify it to `m0 == m1`.

Comment: @sawa, but even then, this would assume that you are calling `super` even if you are not, as long as the names are equal. (aka if `Fu` doesn't inherit from `Foo` and `Fu#bar` method's body is `Foo.new.bar`).

Comment: Just comparison of `mN` won’t work because of both reason described above by @ndn and recursion.

Comment: You should use `base_label` instead of `label`. This will allow the check to work even if `super` is invoked from within a block, e.g. `def bar; -> { super }.call; end`

Comment: Why do you have to check the method owner?