# How to determine the class a method was defined in?

Tags: ruby, reflection

I would like to dynamically determine the class the current method was  defined in.

Here's a static example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class A
  def foo
    puts "I was defined in A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    puts "I was defined in B"
    super
  end
end

A.new.foo
# I was defined in A

B.new.foo
# I was defined in B
# I was defined in A  <- this is the tricky one
```

How can I replace `A` and `B` in the strings above with a dynamic expression?

Apparently, `#{self.class}` does not work. (it would print `I was defined in B` twice for `B`)

I suspect that the answer is *"you can't"*, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: The key to all of it :)

Comment: @ndn I was hoping for `__class__`, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: i think  `Module.nesting.last` might help

Comment: @ndn was not sure of corner cases, thus only a comment (tried it only on OP example in console)

Comment: @WandMaker I was looking for a way to improve http://stackoverflow.com/a/34741488/477037

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
class A
  def foo
    puts "I was defined in #{Module.nesting.first}"
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    puts "I was defined in #{Module.nesting.first}"
    super
  end
end
```

Corrected following WandMaker's suggestion.

Comment: I've selected this answer because `Module.nesting` solves the shown problem and because sawa posted first. However, it does not solve the actual problem I was addressing, so I've posted a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34745608/477037).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Module.nesting.first`.

However, note that this works purely lexically, the same way constants resolution works, so it won't cut it if you have more dynamic needs:

```
Foo = Class.new do
  def foo
    Module.nesting
  end  
end

Foo.new.foo # => []
```

Comment: In case of nested modules, it may not give right answer.  Really depends on what OP needs - class name or module name.

Comment: Try defining `class A` inside a `module C` - it will say method was defined in `C` when you use `Module.nesting.last`.  May be one need to use `Module.nesting.first`

Answer (score 3):

I have this nagging feeling that if you could do this, it would violate object-orientated encapsulation, although I can't quite place my finger on exactly why. So, it shouldn't come as a surprise that it's hard.

I can see a way if you are open to modifying the method definitions:

```
class A
  this = self
  define_method(:foo) do
    puts "I was defined in #{this}"
  end
end

class B < A
  this = self
  define_method(:foo) do
    puts "I was defined in #{this}"
    super()
  end
end

A.new.foo
# I was defined in A

B.new.foo
# I was defined in B
# I was defined in A
```

Comment: Nice one, but still wont work in some dynamic cases. Like defining a method on a class from outside the class. (:

Comment: My understanding is that `Module.nesting` is among the few methods/keywords that work lexically (i.e., behaviour depends on its location in the source code), and hence cannot be passed directly from method to method; its value has to be passed as a variable. Those are `binding`, `__FILE__`,  `__LINE__`, `__dir__`, `Module.nesting`, and perhaps some more.

Comment: @sawa `__method__` is another one.

Comment: @Stefan I thought that the reason WandMaker's deleted answer did not work was because `__method__` isn't lexical. It picks up where it was called from, not where it is written.

Comment: @sawa I think it's lexical, too (in a way). If you have a method `def foo ; __method__ ; end` and you define a new method `define_method(:bar, method(:foo))`, then `bar` will still return `:foo`